# ¿Es suficiente usar RewriteEngine on y desactivar el indexado para evitar el acceso a las imagenes de mi host?

Tags: php, .htaccess, imagen

Hola estoy tratando de evitar que miren mis imagenes usuarios no registrado al menos que hayan iniciado sesion y el archivo php contenga un codigo como este:

```
<img src="<?php if(isset($profile_picture)) echo $profile_picture; ?>" class="img img-rounded" width="100"/>
```

Para eso he escrito en mi archivo .htaccess el siguiente codigo:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?blueemon90.xyz [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
Options All -Indexes
```

El cual bloquea el acceso a la imagen con urls como estas www.mipagina.com/fotos/mifoto.jpg
pero me di cuenta que al colocar esta direccion www.mipagina.com/fotos aparece el indice de la pagina y si doy click en la foto si se visualiza, por lo cual decidi desactivar el indexado de la pagina, es suficiente seguridad con mi codigo en .htaccess y desactivar el indexado?

asi se ve en mi host:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr lo que deseas te recomiendo guardar todas tus imágenes fuera del DocumentRoot de apache y hacer un php que devuelva la imagen cuando lo necesites.

aqui un ejemplo del php que lee y devuelve la imagen.

```html
$file = '.monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

La imagen puede estar en una ruta a la cual apache no tenga acceso (fuera del DocumentRoot) pero si permisos para leerla.